# velocity and acceleration in cylindrical coordinates with $\dot{r} = 0$

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

1. *If the position vector of a particle in the cylindrical coordinates is $\mathbf{r}(t) = r\hat{\mathbf{e_r}}+z\hat{\mathbf{e_z}}$ derive the expression for the velocity using cylindrical polar coordinates.*

I solved it this way $$\dot{\mathbf{r}}(t) = \dot{r}\hat{\mathbf{e_r}}+r\dot{\hat{\mathbf{e_r}}}+\dot{z}\hat{\mathbf{e_z}}+z\dot{\hat{\mathbf{e_z}}} = \dot{r}\hat{\mathbf{e_r}}+r\dot{\theta}\hat{\mathbf{e_\theta}}+\dot{z}\hat{\mathbf{e_z}}$$

As $\dot{\hat{\mathbf{e_z}}} =0$ and by finding the derivative of $\hat{\mathbf{e_r}}$ from the expression it in terms of $i$ and $j$.

2. *Consider the same situation as in the previous problem. Now assume, however, that the radial distance $r$ is constant ($\dot{r} = 0$). Derive the expression for the particle’s acceleration using the cylindrical coordinates.*

$$\mathbf{\ddot{r}(t)} = \ddot{r}\hat{\mathbf{e_r}}+\dot{r}\dot{\hat{\mathbf{e_r}}}+\dot{r}\dot{\theta}\hat{\mathbf{e_\theta}}+r\ddot{\theta}\hat{\mathbf{e_\theta}}+r\dot{\theta}\dot{\hat{\mathbf{e_\theta}}}+\ddot{z}\hat{\mathbf{e_z}}+\dot{z}\dot{\hat{\mathbf{e_z}}} =(\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2)\hat{\mathbf{e_r}}+(2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}+r\ddot{\theta})\hat{\mathbf{e_\theta}}+\ddot{z}\hat{\mathbf{e_z}}  =-r\dot{\theta}^2\hat{\mathbf{e_r}}+r\ddot{\theta}\hat{\mathbf{e_\theta}}+\ddot{z}\hat{\mathbf{e_z}} $$

Do you think it's correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you've got for the acceleration in cylindrical coordinates (for $r$ constant) is correct. 
Check [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec05.pdf) for similar derivations in other coordinate systems.

Comment: as $r$ is constant, do we also have that $z$ is constant? Cause if the motion is on a circle in the $z=0$ plane, then $z$ should be constant. However by the question I don't know if we can assume that. Do you reckon we can?

Comment: Hmmm I don't think so. By saying motion is on a circle then $z$ is of course a constant but I'm not sure we can assume that.